# VSTO: How to programmatically open the OptionsPage of my AddIn

Tags: c#, vsto

I created Outlook Addin (using VIsual Studio 2017, in C# using VSTO) and added a options page dialog to input user credentials.

This options dialog shows up when the user goes to Outlook -> "Options -> Advanced->Addins-> Selects the Addin and then hits the "Addin Options Button" like in the screenshot below:
[image]
Now I want to programmatically open this OptionsPage from the AddIn code.

I already tried to create an instance of the OptionsPage and call the Show() method. But it won't show up.

The following does not work, even though the code is executed, it just does not show the OptionsPage dialog:

```
MyAppOptionPage optionsPage = new myAppOptionPage();
optionsPage.Show();
```

My OptionsPage class is defined as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using RestSharp;

namespace OutlookAddIn4
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public partial class MyAppOptionPage : UserControl, Outlook.PropertyPage
    {
        #region Private Variables

        /// <summary>
        /// This is the parent PropertyPageSite Object.
        /// If we want to enable the Apply Button, we must call the
        /// OnStatusChange() and the PropertyPageSIte Object will check our Dirty Flag. 
        /// </summary>
        Outlook.PropertyPageSite _PropertyPageSite = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// This is our Statusvariable indicating that our Options has changed.
        /// </summary>
        bool _Dirty = false;

        #endregion

        const int captionDispID = -518;

        public MyAppOptionPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(MyAppOptionPage_Load);            
        }

        void MyAppOptionPage_SettingsChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnDirty(true);
        }

        void MyAppOptionPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _PropertyPageSite = GetPropertyPageSite();
            // preset the settings with the current user 
            Properties.Settings.Default.user = ThisAddIn.GetSmtpAddress(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry);
            this.login.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.user;
            this.password.Text = ""; 
            this.serverurl.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.serverurl;
        }

        #region PropertyPage Members

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is called when the user clicks "Apply" or "OK".
        /// </summary>
        public void Apply()
        {
            if (_Dirty)
            {
                // Save Settings
                Properties.Settings.Default.user = this.login.Text;
                // Properties.Settings.Default.token already set in the login process
                Properties.Settings.Default.serverurl = this.serverurl.Text;                
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                // Reset Dirty Flag
                OnDirty(false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function gets the parent PropertyPageSite Object using Reflection.
        /// Must be called in Load event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The parent PropertyPageSite Object</returns>
        Outlook.PropertyPageSite GetPropertyPageSite()
        {
            Type type = typeof(System.Object);
            string assembly = type.Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("mscorlib.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll");
            assembly = assembly.Replace("file:///", "");

            string assemblyName = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assembly).FullName;
            Type unsafeNativeMethods = Type.GetType(System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assemblyName, "System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods"));

            Type oleObj = unsafeNativeMethods.GetNestedType("IOleObject");
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = oleObj.GetMethod("GetClientSite");
            object propertyPageSite = methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);

            return (Outlook.PropertyPageSite)propertyPageSite;
        }


        public void OnDirty(bool dirty)
        {
            _Dirty = dirty;
            _PropertyPageSite.OnStatusChange();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The Dirty Property used form parent PropertyPageSite object.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Dirty
        {
            get { return _Dirty; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The GetPageInfo function used form parent PropertyPageSite object,
        /// when user requests help.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="HelpFile">The name of the Helpfile.</param>
        /// <param name="HelpContext">The Index of the HelpContext requested.</param>
        public void GetPageInfo(ref string HelpFile, ref int HelpContext)
        {
            // TODO: Implement Helpfile
        }

        #endregion

        bool Outlook.PropertyPage.Dirty
        {
            get
            {
                return _Dirty;
            }
        }
        void Outlook.PropertyPage.GetPageInfo(ref string helpFile, ref int helpContext)
        {

        }

        [DispId(captionDispID)]
        public string PageCaption
        {
            get
            {
                return "MyApp Settings";
            }
        }

        private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnDirty(true);
            try
            {                
                ThisAddIn.myMyAppAPI = new MyAppAPI(ThisAddIn.GetSmtpAddress(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry), this.serverurl.Text, this.login.Text, this.password.Text);
                this.testresult.Text = "Login succcessfull!";
            }
            catch (ApplicationException exception)
            {
                this.testresult.Text = "Login unsuccessfull.Check your parameters above! "+exception.Message;        
            }        
        }

        private void textChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO is textChanged the correct event to handle for key changes
            OnDirty(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put your option dialog in the backstage?

Comment: what do you mean with backstage? btw i decided to build my own form because having an optionspage is not very userfriendly. i also think that other addins don‘t use optionpages

Comment: see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2013/04/05/customizing-office-2013-backstage/ - you could open your dialog from somewhere backstage...